# Use Leiningen to build frontend with Gulp

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, build, gulp, frontend

I have a pretty standard Ring application with some Compojure RESTfull endpoints. We also have a frontend application based on Polymer, Bower and Gulp. So I thought it would be nice to distribute this application in one package (which means having a build which will in the end produce a WAR file consisting of both backend and frontend part which can be uploaded anywhere without any other dependencies).

However I started to dig into the Leiningen and apparently there is no plugin which would support this need. So before I am gonna build something like that on my own, is there some other way how to do this? Or am I thinking about the problem in the wrong way?

P.S. The ultimate goal is to deploy application to AWS, I've done it already via  [elastic-beanstalk](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-beanstalk) plugin and it seemd to me pretty smooth (just build the WAR, pass it to the plugin and it will take care about the rest).

Answer (score 2):

I have built projects with similarities. I avoided using leiningen/lein-plugins to build the frontend and instead built it with webpack, while letting lein compile the clojure into an uberjar. The build artifacts from webpack were output to the resources path that was declared in project.clj and packaged into an uberjar. The web server was also bundled in the uberjar and was configured to serve from that path. I used [luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/) as a project template.

It seems like you could do something similar here. Use gulp to build the frontend and package into a war that can be deployed to elastic beanstalk. My build script from package.json was this: `npm install && NODE_ENV=production webpack -p && lein uberjar`.

So, you don't need to have a lein plugin to build your frontend. I found it easier to let another build tool do that work.